# Adding Custom Image To Header Via New Customizer Setting

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to add a custom image setting to a custom panel/section for the header.

In functions.php, I used:

```
$wp_customize->add_setting('swag_header_logo');
$wp_customize->add_control(new WP_Customize_Upload_Control($wp_customize,'swag_header_logo',array(
     'label'      => __('Logo', 'frontend-theme'),
     'section'    => 'swag_header_content_section',
     'settings'   => 'swag_header_logo'
 )));
```

Which shows up and seems to work in the customizer. However, when trying to get it to show up in the header, it gives the error:

> Fatal error : Call to undefined function swag_header_logo() in
>   /home/xxxxxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/frontend-theme/header.php
>   on line 551

The code I used in the header.php:

```
$swag_header_logo = get_theme_mod('swag_header_logo');
```

and

```
<?php swag_header_logo(); ?>
```

How do I fix the error?

Answer (score 0):

First part of your code looks correct - it's hard to say if it will work, because it's only part of it, but there is nothing wrong with the part you've shown.

Problem lies in this line:

```
<?php swag_header_logo(); ?>
```

You haven't defined such function anywhere in your code, so you can't call it - and that's what the error is saying ("Call to undefined function swag_header_logo()").

### So how to fix it?

In this line:

```
$swag_header_logo = get_theme_mod('swag_header_logo');
```

you get the ID of attachment set as `swag_header_logo` and you store this ID in `$swag_header_logo` variable.

So if you want to display the image, just use:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image( $swag_header_logo, '<SIZE>' ); // change size to real value
```

or if you want only the URL of the image:

```
echo wp_get_attachment_image_url( $swag_header_logo, '<SIZE>' ); // change size to real value
```

Comment: Didn't work for me, url just comes up (unknown)

Comment: You say the first part of code is missing some, what is it missing?

Comment: this seems to work: `echo esc_url(get_theme_mod('swag_header_logo'));`

Comment: It all depends what exactly do you store in that option and how do you process it.